# Como hago que los objetos de un array tengan el mismo nombre pero no tengan los mismos datos?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

El problema es que cada vez que hago el push el id que había pusheado antes a el array users se actualiza con el nombre del nuevo id.
Osea cada vez que hago push, todos los id que están dentro del array, cambian, y quiero que se mantengan, que se mantengan y que se agregue el nuevo.

```javascript
const {Client, Intents} = require('discord.js'); 
const discord = require('discord.js')

var users = []; 
var id = {};
var msj = ""; 

const client = new discord.Cliente({
  intents: [0,0,0], 
}); 

client.on('message', message => {
  msj = message.author

  if(message.content == "!create-wallet") {

    // id +=1; 

    id = {
      name: msj, 
      money: 0
    }; 

    users.push([id]); 

    // ...
  }
})
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Leectura recomendara para saber [ask], el codigo no debe subirse en imagenes, para eso hay herramientas especiales que te permiten agregar codigo cuando estas redactando la pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, y sobre el tema principal hay algo en lo que me puedas ayudar?